# Problems with ATI V9800

Tags: ati, video, display

I just installed 12.04.1 to Dell R5500 workstation.  The video card I am using is the ATI V9800.  After  the reboot the display is fragmented and I am unable to read the desktop.  Has anyone seen this problem before and any suggestion on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are available for the card:

1. Upon boot, enter recovery mode: Hold the shift key while the machine is booting until you see the Grub menu. Scroll with the up and down arrow keys to "Ubuntu, with Linux {kernel version} (Recovery Mode)" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. When Recovery Mode boots, you will see a menu. Scroll down with the arrow keys to the line that says `network    Enable networking` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. When you see the menu again (`fsck` might take a while), scroll down to `root Drop to root shell prompt` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. You will be taken to the prompt immediately. Type `apt-get purge fglrx && apt-get install fglrx` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Once you see the prompt again, reboot with `reboot` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: There is no "software and updates" program installed n 12.04, but by querying in dash for additional or driver the additional drivers app will be shown and it can be started

Comment: I am brand new to ubuntu and this is my first time installing it.  However, when the machine boots up the screen is so distorted i cant no read anything.  Is there a way to access the dash in a command prompt?

Comment: I will edit my answer.